# What do these functions mean?

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

I recently got acquainted to the max min functions. They seem quite confusing to understand and plot.

For example: $min (|x|,|y|)=1$
What does this mean?
I sense these mean that first we plot the equality; And then cancel those portions of the graph that lie above another portion of graph to get the minimum graph.

I reduce this function into:

$ |x|=1 $ or $ |y|=1 $
$x=1,-1 $ or $ y=1,-1 $

Plotting these I get [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mriejrchnc).

On cancelling the portions of the graph which have some of the graph below them we get [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/yoxdwzguww).

But desmos tells me the graph is [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/1hyg1am6bu).

Obviously my understanding of the functions is incorrect.
Can somebody walk me through how to make and understand the graph in the example I mentioned. Or you could use any other similar example as you wish.

I would be happy to further clarify the question if anyone asks.

Comment: The equation is invariant by the changes of variable $x\to\pm x$, $y\to\pm y$, and $x\to y$, $y\to x$. Each of these changes of variables corresponds to a symmetry of the graph with respect to the axes, origin, or with respect to $x=y$. Therefore, it is enough to assume $y\geq x\geq 0$. In that case, $\min(|x|,|y|)=x=1$. Therefore, you get the ray $\{(x,y):\ x=1, y\geq x\}$. Now, you just need to take symmetries with respect to the axes, origin, and to the diagonal line $x=y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have forgotten that $$|x|\geq |y|$$ or $$|x|<|y|$$ must hold.
You will get two cases:
$$\min(|x|,|y|)=|y|$$ if $$|x|\geq |y|$$
and
$$\min(|x|,|y|)=|x|$$ if $$|x|<|y|$$

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit please?

Comment: I have added some lines for you!

Comment: I understood, Thanks and nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

$\min (|x|,|y|)=1$ means: take $y$ and $x$ value, if one of them has absolute value of $1$ and the other has absolute value of $1$ **or more** plot this point.

So we get the lines:$$\min(|x|,|y|)=|x|=\begin{cases}|x|=1,y\ge 1\\|x|=1,y\le -1\end{cases}\\\min(|x|,|y|)=|y|=\begin{cases}x\ge1,|y|=1\\x\le-1,|y|=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Good Answer!, That really helped.